# How to update the Checkboxes inside a Checkbox List component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, storybook

Having the following CheckBox Component:

```
    import {
      StyledCheckboxIndicator,
      StyledCheckboxRoot,
      StyledCheckIcon,
      StyledMinusIcon,
    } from './form-checkbox.styles';
    interface FormCheckboxProps extends Checkbox.CheckboxProps {
  checkboxIndicatorProps?: Checkbox.CheckboxIndicatorProps;
  isError?: boolean;
}
    
    export const FormCheckbox = ({
      checkboxIndicatorProps,
      isError,
      ...checkboxRootProps
    }: FormCheckboxProps) => {
      const { disabled, checked } = checkboxRootProps;
      return (
        <StyledCheckboxRoot {...checkboxRootProps} $isError={isError}>
          <StyledCheckboxIndicator {...checkboxIndicatorProps}>
              <StyledCheckIcon disabled={disabled} />
          </StyledCheckboxIndicator>
        </StyledCheckboxRoot>
      );
    };
```

I want to use it to create a Checkbox List component that has multiple checkboxes, allowing the user for multiple selection.

The component is in the Stotybook, here is the code:

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import { FormCheckbox } from 'components/atoms';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { CheckboxList } from './checkbox-list';

interface StorybookCheckboxListSetupProps {
   handleCheckboxOnChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
   currentOption: Array<string>;
}


const options = [
  {
    label: 'Beginner',
    value: 'first',
    name: 'checkbox-list',
  },
  {
    label: 'Intermediate',
    value: 'second',
    name: 'checkbox-list',
  },
  {
    label: 'Advanced',
    value: 'third',
    name: 'checkbox-list',
  },
];

export default {
  title: 'Molecules/CheckboxList',
  component: CheckboxList,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof CheckboxList>;

const CheckboxListSetup = ({
  handleCheckboxOnChange,
  currentOption,
}: StorybookCheckboxListSetupProps) => {
  console.log('currentOption: ', currentOption);
  return (
    <CheckboxList>
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <FormCheckbox
            key={option.label}
            checked={currentOption.includes(option.label)}
            id={option.value}
            aria-label="Toggle checkbox"
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxOnChange}
          />
        );
      })}
    </CheckboxList>
  );
};

const useControlledCheckboxList = (initialValues: Array<string> = ['Beginner', 'Advanced']) => {
  const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = useState<Array<string>>(initialValues);
  const handleCheckboxOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log('EVENT: ', event);
    let updatedList = [...currentOption];
    if (event.target.checked) {
      updatedList = [...currentOption, event.target.value];
    } else {
      updatedList.splice(currentOption.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
    }
    setCurrentOption(updatedList);
  };
  return { currentOption, handleCheckboxOnChange };
};

export const checkboxList: ComponentStory<typeof CheckboxList> = () => {
  const { currentOption, handleCheckboxOnChange } = useControlledCheckboxList();

  return (
    <CheckboxListSetup
      currentOption={currentOption}
      handleCheckboxOnChange={handleCheckboxOnChange}
    />
  );
};
```

It loads the component correctly with 'Beginner' and 'Advanced' checked but when I click nothing happens, the checkboxes are not updating nor the log is in the console.

You may say to change `onChange={() => handleCheckboxOnChange}` with `onChange={handleCheckboxOnChange}` but still doesn't work throwing the error:

> Type '((e: ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined' is not
> assignable to type 'FormEventHandler | undefined'.
> Type '(e: ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to
> type 'FormEventHandler'.
> Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'FormEvent' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent'.
> Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
> Type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.
> Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and
> 338 more.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have duplicate code perhaps?
`interface StorybookCheckboxListSetupProps {
   handleCheckboxOnChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
   currentOption: Array<string>;
}

interface StorybookCheckboxListSetupProps {
   handleCheckboxOnChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
   currentOption: Array<string>;
}`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I copied the code twice there, it doesn't affect the issue presented here

Answer (score 0):

This code will not execute properly. You're saying "when I click, return a function but don't execute that function."

`onChange={() => handleCheckboxOnChange}`

So in your case the correct way seems to be you need to pass the event to your handler which you're missing:

Try using this:

`onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxOnChange(e)}`

Although this effectively does that:

`onChange={handleCheckboxOnChange}`

So the issue appears to be elsewhere. The type definition is saying it was the type definition of `FormEventHandler | undefined` but you're setting it to `(e: ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined`. I would adjust the interface to start.

Comment: I've tried this approach too, maybe it needs `e` to be defined somehow because it returns this error: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: I don't find that type definition anywhere...

Comment: Strange. Could you setup a barebones sandbox to reproduce the issue?